# Filter dataframe by values being subset of a given set

Tags: r

Let's say we have some persons that do different activities.

```
data <- data.frame(person=c('A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C'), activity=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2))
```

I would like to filter the data by persons that only do 'relevant activities' where relevant activities are defined by another vector.

```
relevant_activities <- c(1,2)
```

Hence, a person's activity values need to be a subset of the relevant activities.

Expected outcome:

```
  person activity
1      C        1
2      C        2
```

I tried something like this, without success:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  group_by(person) %>%
  filter(all(relevant_activities %in% activity))
```

Comment: filter( activity %in% relevant_activities)

Comment: @mr.joshuagordon, this would remove rows of non-relevant activities. But I would like to filter by the persons.

Comment: Try by adding `all` i.e. `data %>% group_by(person) %>% filter(all(activity %in% relevant_activities))`

Comment: filter( sum(activity %in% relevant_activities ) == length(activity))

Comment: @akrun, your suggestion works, thanks. Feel free to formulate an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can wrap with `all`

```
data %>% 
     group_by(person) %>% 
     filter(all(activity %in% relevant_activities))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `data.table`

```
library("data.table")

D <- data.table(person=c('A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C'), activity=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2))
relevant_activities <- c(1,2)

D[person %in% D[, all(activity %in% relevant_activities), person][, person[V1]]]
```

or with a key on the datatable:

```
D <- data.table(person=c('A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C'),
        activity=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2), key="person")
relevant_activities <- c(1,2)

D[D[, all(activity %in% relevant_activities), person][, person[V1]]]
```