# Keep the key that has only one specific value in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data frame

```
filen<-c('510-1','510-2','510-2','510-2','510-3','510-3','510-4')
disp<-c('g','ng','ng','ng','g','ng','ng')

df<-data.frame(filen,disp)


  filen disp
1 510-1    g
2 510-2   ng
3 510-2   ng
4 510-2   ng
5 510-3    g
6 510-3   ng
7 510-4   ng
```

Basically I want to isolate the file numbers where `ng` is the only type of disp associated with that filen. So that I get a dataset like this. How do I do this using dplyr

```
filen disp
510-2  ng
510-4  ng
```

Comment: Pretty similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53705012/5325862) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43689057/5325862)

Comment: @akrun I don't think the question is an exact dupe of those, which is why I didn't vote to close, but I do think they are similar enough to help the OP and future users of the site. That doesn't have anything to do with you answering, beyond the fact that your nearly identical answers on those posts are what I'm saying would help the OP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can group by 'filen', `filter` the groups where `all` the 'disp' values are 'ng' and get the `distinct` rows

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(filen) %>%
   filter( all(disp == 'ng')) %>%
   distinct
# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Groups:   filen [2]
#  filen disp 
#   <fct> <fct>
#1 510-2 ng   
#2 510-4 ng
```

---

Or

```
df %>% 
   distinct %>%
   group_by(filen) %>%
   filter(n_distinct(disp) == 1, disp == 'ng')
```

---

Or we can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(unique(df))[,  .SD[uniqueN(disp)==1 & disp == "ng"], filen]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using base R, we one option can be to calculate the frequency of `df` using `table`, find the `filen` which have `ng` value greater than 0 and `g` value equal to 0 and keep only `unique` rows.

```
df1 <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(df))
unique(df[df$filen %in% rownames(df1)[df1$ng > 0 & df1$g == 0], ])

#  filen disp
#2 510-2   ng
#7 510-4   ng
```

Or with `ave`

```
unique(df[ave(df$disp == "ng", df$filen, FUN = all), ])
```